# Does this series converge conditionally $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n^{\frac{1}{10}}}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification, summation

> $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n^{\frac{1}{10}}}$

According to my understanding, if $\sum\left|a_n\right|$ diverges but $\sum a_n$ converges, then the series is conditionally convergent.

For $\sum\left|a_n\right|$ my series can be test via the p-series test and since $\frac{1}{10} \lt 1$ it diverges.

So next I test $\sum a_n$ using the alternating series test and find that it is a decreasing series and the limit converges to 0.

Thus, I came to the conclusion that this is conditionally convergent.  Is this correct?

Comment: grouping the terms by two it is absolutely convergent : $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n n^{-0.1} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty (2n)^{-0.1}-(2n-1)^{-0.1} =  \sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_{2n-1}^{2n} \frac{0.1}{x^{1.1}} dx <\sum_{n=1}^\infty 0.1 (2n-1)^{-1.1}$

Comment: @user1952009 This is not what "absolutely convergent" means. Grouping the terms as one pleases is not allowed, it becomes *another* series. cf. Riemann's Rearrangement Theorem.

Comment: @ClementC. I don't see your point, what I wrote is perfectly correct

Comment: It does change things. You are looking at another series, $\sum_n b_n$ with $b_n = a_{2n-1}+a_{2n}$. That *other* series is absolutely convergent, but $\sum_n a_n$ is *not*.

Comment: @ClementC. : I didn't say it was, I said grouping the terms by two it is...

Comment: (and I messed up with a minus sign, but nobody cares)

Comment: But that statement is utterly confusing, then. What does your "it" refer to? Given that the OP is asking about a specific series, while your statement is only true if "it" refers to a different (related) series you implicitly define after using the pronoun, it can only bring confusion. (Especially since it's about a point the OP was not asking about, and most likely not considering to begin with)

Comment: @ClementC. lol come on I just wanted to show him it is an absolutely convergent series in disguise, it is useful for him

Comment: True, but then so is the (divergent, so not even well-defined) series $\sum_n (-1)^n$... :)

Comment: (as a last comment: basically, any conditionally convergent series you can use the alternating series test on will allow the same grouping you used: pairing even and odd terms will result in an absolutely convergent series, as all terms have the same sign)

Comment: @ClementC. yes that's what I wanted to show him

Comment: @user1952009 The original series is conditionally convergent while the one upon grouping is absolutely convergent.  Both have the same value.

Comment: @Dr.MV lol... yes that's what I said in my 1st comment

Comment: @user1952009 Yes, I was clarifying only.

Comment: $-\eta\left(1 \over 10\right)$.

Comment: @the_new_guy After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\color{green}\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is. (Note however that to be fully correct, the statement you make should read that "$(\lvert a_n\rvert)_n$ is a decreasing sequence," not that "$\sum_n a_n$ is a decreasing series.")

Comment: All too easy... +1

Comment: @Dr.MV "I like my proofs like I like my eggs."?

Comment: Over easy I presume.

Comment: Or scrambled so nobody can refute?

Comment: Actually Benedict, but then I fear I'm missing the point.

Comment: Or poached - taken from another's proof.

Comment: "I like my proofs like I don't like my elephants?"

Comment: Do you mean an African elephant or an Indian one?  (And that was an homage to a movie you likeky have seen).

Comment: If it were swallows, I'd say Monty Pythons.

Comment: And you would be correct.  It was actually African or European.  But it was only an homage, and thus need not be identical.

Answer (score 0):

A monotonically descending alternating series converges, is that series a A monotonically descending alternating series ?